# Clustering with lat longs and other constaints

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-computing, hierarchical-clustering

I have data with different localities with their Lat Longs and their respective populations.
I have to cluster these localities in a way that max radius of a cluster must be 7 kms and minimum population of a cluster can be 5K.
Can somebody please help me with the python code. Or any ideas as how can I proceed with this.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. We can help you troubleshoot existing code and solve any issues you might have with that. Please edit your question and include the code you have.

Comment: You can use any clustering algorithm like KMeans Clustering with the stopping criteria of the 5K elements and area of 7Kms of radius which can be computed by the la long.